# How do I use map in React Native to create separate buttons?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a simple quiz app in React Native:

`App.js`

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.quizData = [
      {
        question: 'Who wrote A Game Of Thrones?',
        correctAnswer: 'George RR Martin',
        possibleAnswers: ['JK Rowling', 'Phillip Pulman', 'George RR Martin' ]
      },
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MultiChoice answers={this.quizData[0].possibleAnswers}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And my `MultiChoice` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class MultiChoice extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
          <Text style={styles.button}>{ this.props.answers.map(answer => answer) }</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
  }
})

export default MultiChoice;
```

I don't get any errors and all the elements of the array are displayed in the same button, but I would like to have **three separate** buttons. I wrote the same code in React and it worked, but in React Native it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `map` just returns each element, unmodified -- it does nothing. It will then create *one single `<Text>` component with all the text*. Just have the `map` operation return a separate `<Text>` component for every element to achieve separate buttons:

```
{ this.props.answers.map(answer => <Text style={styles.button}>{answer}</Text>) }
```

And this will create separate `<Text>` components with the strings.